# Unable to insert Date into HSQLdb

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am using HSQL as an in memory database for testing. However, I am unable to insert a date into the column. 
Below is my table creation script:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;

create table OWN_TABLE (
    ID DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    CAPACITY_SUPPLY_DATE DATE ,
);
```

And the queries I tried:

```
INSERT INTO OWN_TABLE(ID, NAME, CAPACITY_SUPPLY_DATE) VALUES(2, '4813', '2090-07-15');
```

But it gives

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid datetime format
```

I also tried `2090-07-15 00:00:00` but it didn't work.

Assuming oracle syntax might work, I tried:

```
INSERT INTO LABS_CAPACITY_SUPPLY(ID, SHIP_NODE, CAPACITY_SUPPLY_DATE) VALUES(1, '4813', 'TO_DATE(2090-07-30,"yyy-MM-dd")');
```

But got `Unparseable date: "TO_DATE(2090-07-30,"yyy-MM-dd")"`

Can somebody please tell me the right way to insert dates into HSQL. I have the `2.3.2` jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a proper standard SQL `date` literal:

```
INSERT INTO OWN_TABLE
  (ID, NAME, CAPACITY_SUPPLY_DATE) 
VALUES
  (2, '4813', DATE '2090-07-15');
```

Or, if you do want to use the `to_date()` function then don't put it into single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO LABS_CAPACITY_SUPPLY
  (ID, SHIP_NODE, CAPACITY_SUPPLY_DATE) 
VALUES
  (1, '4813', TO_DATE(2090-07-30,'yyy-MM-dd'));
```

Note that for the `to_date()` function the case of the format string does not matter. `'yyyy-MM-dd'` is the same as `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'yyyy-mm-dd'`. The format is **not** the one used for Java's `SimpleDateFormat`.

---

If you are doing this from within a Java program you should not use any of the above solutions. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead:

```
java.sql.Date dt = ...;
PreparedStatement pstmt = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO OWN_TABLE(ID, NAME, CAPACITY_SUPPLY_DATE) VALUES(?,?,?)";
pstmt.setInt(1, 2);
pstmt.setString(2, "4813");
pstmt.setDate(3, dt);
```

How you construct the instance of `java.sql.Date` depends on where you get the data from. You could use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the user's input. Or you could use LocalDate if you are using Java 8, e.g. `java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocaleDate.of(2090,7,30))`

Comment: I keep getting `invalide datetime format`. It seems the `CAPACITY_SUPPLY_DATE` column is being treated as `datetime`. What should I do to treat it just as a simple date?

Comment: @SudhanshuShekhar: this works for me with the CREATE TABLE statement you have specified in your question (but I am using 2.3.4). Do you get the same error with a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: Try using standard timestamp literal `timestamp '2090-07-15 00:00:00'` if HSQLDB expects a timestamp

Comment: I upgraded my `hsql` version to `2.3.4` and everything works. Seems defining a column as `DATE` in `2.3.2` still treated it as a datetime object. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SudhanshuShekhar: that is probably a result of the `SYNTAX ORA` because Oracle does not have a "real" date (i.e. one without a `time`)